# How to give a substringed object to the view? Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi i am just starting with programming and i am trying to create a very simple blog with Express.js and Mongoose.Whit this code i am printing 6 articles from my database(simple Article Schema: title,content and user) on the front page of my blog.But how can i not display the whole content but just the start 100 letters from the content.How can i pass it to the view?

```
index: (req, res) => {
  Articles.find({}).limit(6).populate('author').then(articles => {
      res.render('home/index', { articles: articles})
  })
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
res.render('home/index', { articles: articles });
```

you'd have to use:

```
res.render('home/index', { articles: articles.map(shorten) });
```

and implement the `shorten()` function as follows:

```
function shorten(article) {
    return {
        title: article.title,
        content. article.content.slice(0, 100),
    };
}
```

Just change the key names for `title` and `content` to whatever you're using because you didn't say anything on how your data looks like.

Alternatively you can change this:

```
res.render('home/index', { articles: articles.map(shorten) });
```

to something like:

```
articles.forEach(article => {
    article.content = article.content.slice(0, 100);
});
res.render('home/index', { articles: articles });
```

if you're sure that you won't need the original values in your `articles` array later.

Comment: Thank you :) I did it with the second way and its working just like i want it :)

Comment: "content." should "be content:" for object property